# Использование селекторов

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, подскажите, как правильно прописать селекторы, что бы все объекты 6 и объекты 8,9, не находились еще в одной рамке.

[image: Как должно получится]

```css
.content .right-bar div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left-bar">
    <div class="four">4</div>
    <div class="seven">7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-bar">
    <div class="five">5</div>
    <div class="center">
      <div>6</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div class="eight">8</div>
      <div class="nine">9</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я правильно поняла задачу?

```css
.content .left-bar .four,.seven, .right-bar .five, .center div, .bottom .eight, .nine {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left-bar">
    <div class="four">4</div>
    <div class="seven">7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-bar">
    <div class="five">5</div>
    <div class="center">
      <div>6</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div class="eight">8</div>
      <div class="nine">9</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да спасибо, я уже конечно разобрался, но интересно, можно ли сделать более компактно?

Comment: .content .left-bar .four,.seven, .right-bar .five, .center div, .bottom .eight, .nine - Вы это хотите сделать более компактно? Или html?

Answer (score 4):

Обводить элементы `div`, которые находятся непосредственно (являются подэлементами первого уровня) в элементах `.right-bar`, которые находятся где-то внутри `.content`:

```css
.content .right-bar > div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left-bar">
    <div class="four">4</div>
    <div class="seven">7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-bar">
    <div class="five">5</div>
    <div class="center">
      <div>6</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div class="eight">8</div>
      <div class="nine">9</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, некорректно я озвучил вопрос, я имел ввиду, чтобы все цифры находились в рамке, но .center и .bottom не являлся рамкой